# Strange AssertionError in asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm trying to mark future done by timeout with this code:

```
import asyncio


@asyncio.coroutine
def greet():
    while True:
        print('Hello World')
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)

@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    future = asyncio.async(greet())
    loop.call_later(3, lambda: future.set_result(True))
    yield from future
    print('Ready')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

"Timer" loop.call_later sets result to future after 3 seconds. It works, but I'm getting exception too:

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
Ready
Exception in callback <bound method Task._wakeup of Task(<greet>)<result=True>>(Future<result=None>,)
handle: Handle(<bound method Task._wakeup of Task(<greet>)<result=True>>, (Future<result=None>,))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\asyncio\events.py", line 39, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\asyncio\tasks.py", line 337, in _wakeup
    self._step(value, None)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\asyncio\tasks.py", line 267, in _step
    '_step(): already done: {!r}, {!r}, {!r}'.format(self, value, exc)
AssertionError: _step(): already done: Task(<greet>)<result=True>, None, None
```

What can mean this AssertionError? Am I doing something wrong setting future done by loop.call_later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What causes the exception: `greet` continues to run even after the `future.set_result` call; By changing`while True` with `if True`, you will get what I mean.

How about using [`asyncio.Event`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#event)?

```
import asyncio


@asyncio.coroutine
def greet(stop):
    while not stop.is_set():
        print('Hello World')
        yield from asyncio.sleep(1)


@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    stop = asyncio.Event()
    loop.call_later(3, stop.set)
    yield from asyncio.async(greet(stop))
    print('Ready')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call `future.set_result()` yourself. The event loop sets the result of the future after the task returns.